# Usage of flock for copying files

Tags: bash, slurm, flock

I am running array jobs on slurm, so every job needs to copy a file from a local directory to a temporary one. This `cp` should not occur simultaneously.

This is the code I came up with:

```
mydirectory=mydb
LOCKFILE_1=${mydirectory}.lock
set -e
(
    flock -w 3600 200 # Wait for the lockfile for max. 1 hour (3600 s), to not block the queue forever in case of dead lock files.
    cp -r ${mydirectory} $TMPDIR/newdestinationdirectory
) 200>$LOCKFILE_1
set +e
```

Is this code doing the right thing?
Or do I need

```
rm -f $LOCKFILE_1
```

for removing the lockfile again?

Comment: `This cp should not occur simultaneously`. why? You can read concurrently. You can't read&write at the same time - but there is no write shown here, so until the destination is unique for each job, just copy in parallel.

Comment: The sysadmin might get mad (he did so in the past...)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to limit the load on the file system and network. There is Slurm's [sbcast](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbcast.html) command which is for such cases. You can only copy single files, so you should tar the directory before broadcasting to all nodes:

```
tar cf ${mydirectory}.tar $mydirectory
sbcast ${mydirectory}.tar $TMPDIR/
srun -n ${SLURM_JOB_NUM_NODES} --ntasks-per-node=1 "tar xf ${mydirectory}.tar -C $TMPDIR/"
```

This can only be done inside a job allocation (e.g. inside a jobscript)!

Comment: this works for all currently active slurm jobs, right?

Comment: It has to be run inside a jobscript or job allocation. So not for already running jobs.